# Javascript console.log does not show derived class name - inheritance - classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance, console.log

I'm playing with ECMAScript6 classes.

I still don't understand why the following code :

```
"use strict";

class A {}
class B extends A {}

let b = new B();
console.log(b);
```

Displays :

*A { }*

Instead of :

*B { }*

Live Example:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    class A {}
    class B extends A {
        foo() {
        }
    }

    let b = new B();
    console.log(b);
})();
```

```html
Open the console. Works only on very up-to-date browsers (such as Chrome 43+).
```

---

How can I have the expected logical output *B { }* on console.log ?

May I need to specify my class name to be "*B*" ? Is there such an option to pass, or an attribute or a function to define ?

---

T.J. Crowder got it : It is a referenced bug on Chrome.

Everybody, can you star this bug to increase its priority ?

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510688

Comment: Tested to be the case on Chrome 44 (OSX)

Comment: Yeah, Chrome 43 (Linux) as well.

Comment: Chrome 45 beta, too. OSX

Comment: To be fair, what it displays is technically correct since an instance of B is also an instance of A. To really check you can use `instanceof`.

Comment: @slebetman: By that logic, it should show `Object {}`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's what consoles of all browsers used to show for constructor based objects wasn't it?

Comment: @slebetman: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what browser you're using, but I figure it has to be Chrome, given the style of the output you showed and that it runs at all. (If I run that in IE11, I get `[object Object] {}` instead. If I run it in Firefox, I get an error — because Firefox [doesn't support `class` yet](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#class).)

I can't think of any reason other than a bug in Chrome. Support for `class` is **very** new to Chrome, it could easily be that the devtools just aren't quite handling it correctly yet. <s>I didn't find a bug report on http://crbug.com in a quick search, you might want to file one.</s> But [you did find it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510688).

It really should be showing `B` with your code, not `A`. It *does* with the equivalent old-fashioned way to do it:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  function A() {}

  function B() {
    A.call(this);
  }
  B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
  B.prototype.constructor = B;

  var b = new B();
  console.log(b);
})();
```

```html
Open the console.
```

Comment: You got it : It appears to be a bug referenced on crbug : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510688

Comment: @DenisTruffaut: Good find!